# jQuery click event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below JS code;

```
var $divContent = $("<div />");
$divContent.on('click.mypop', function(e){
alert(e.type);
}
```

So there is a div on page with some text content.

My question is there is no element with class "mypop" and still my code goes inside the click handler when I do click action on the div?

How is this possible ?

Comment: Please review the `.on()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @Satpal this is not a custom event, it is a normal `click` event in `mypop` namespace

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/). First param is the event type and has nothing to do with anything in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching the handler to event `click.mypop`. That is just a `click` event in `mypop` namespace. You can read more about it in section "Event names and namespaces" here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ In short, namespaces are used to be able to attach and remove specific groups of events without disturbing others.

If you want to attach your handler to elements with `mypop` class inside the div, you should attach it like this:

```
var $divContent = $("<div />");
$divContent.on('click', '.mypop', function(e){
    alert(e.type);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're binding the click event incorrecty. Check on the official API documentation on how to use `.on()`. It should  be as follow:

```
var $divContent = $("<div />");
$divContent.on('click', '.mypop', function(e){
    alert(e.type);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no event like `click.mypop`.
Format: `$(staticElement).on(event, selector, function)`.
E.g.: `$(document).on('click', '.mypop', function(e){alert(e.type);})`